# When should I reverse normalizations to evaluate loss?

Tags: neural-network, predictive-modeling, prediction, normalization

If I am training a neural network and have normalized the data before-hand, should I reverse the normalization to calculate the loss?

[This tutorial provides an example of this method.](https://machinelearningmastery.com/timedistributed-layer-for-long-short-term-memory-networks-in-python/)

What if I'm using batch normalization? [From this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55683231/how-to-reverse-batch-normalization) it looks like there are ways to reverse it but my question is more along the lines of should I bother.

My first thought was that it would depend on the problem but I could not think of a problem where I would not want to minimize the error in the actual units of the problem

Comment: Am not sure about error-term. Are you talking about sampling error or measurement error or outlier

Comment: I mean the loos function fed to `model.compile()`. Just corrected it in the post